# Configure multiple search suffix domains in Unifi Security Gateway (dhcp option 119 domain search)

Tags: dhcp, ubiquiti, unifi

I would like to have the DHCP server in my Unifi Security Gatway include multiple domain search entries as part of [DHCP option 119](https://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml) so that I can use shortnames for multiple suffixes like:

- host -> host.example.com
- anotherhost -> anotherhost.home.arpa
- container -> container.somehost.lxd

Currently the `Domain Name: example.com` entry in the Network settings is used for the `option domain-search "example.com"` entry in `/opt/vyatta/etc/dhcpd.conf`, but this field does not allow you to specify multiple entries (probably for good reason).

I attempted to enable a [custom DHCP option](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/360012097513-UniFi-USG-How-to-Configure-Custom-DHCP-Options) for Code 119, but this seems to use a raw hex value in the config file like `option domain-search 65:78:61:6d:70:6c:65:2e:63:6f:6d:20:68:6f:6d:65:2e:61:72:70:61;` for a value of "example.com home.arpa". It also doesn't clear the original entry, which likely causes issues with how the values get [encoded on the wire](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3397#section-2). I tried various values but none seem to show up correctly in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases`

How can I configure multiple search suffixes for my Unifi network?

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is quite old, however using the text type as a custom DHCP option didn't work for me.
I needed to add a custom code 119 of type hex array and convert the search list to hex.
I wrote a simple python [script](https://gist.github.com/SweBarre/0f3b984fd655601d4f13e6af065fde77) to convert the domain list and just adding the output from that script worked like a charm for me.

Comment: I googled around a lot and this answer is what finally worked for me. Using USG-3P firmware version 4.4.56 and Unifi controller version 7.0.23.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've figured this out by now, but you can set a "text" type for a custom DHCP option, then just enter a comma separated domain list.  Note: it overrides the default provided by the DHCP server, so you need to include that too.

Comment: In UDM (my current Network app version is 7.3.83), the Text option type works for option 119 (hex did not work for me).  I simply provided a space-delimited list of domains as the text value, with code 119.  I haven't tried commas, but that might work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this in v2.0.9-hotfix.6, but I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere. Here's what worked for me:

```
configure
set service dhcp-server shared-network-name [your dhcp network name] subnet [your IP subnet] domain-name "subnet1.x.com subnet2.x.com x.com"
commit ; save
```

You should end up with correctly formatted `option domain-name` and `option domain-search` lines in `/opt/vyatta/etc/dhcpd.conf`.